# Use my own server to stream 360 videos

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming, software, webvideos, 360video

YouTube seems to limit the quality / resolution / data size of 360 videos that can be uploaded. If I want to serve higher quality content, what do I need to do?

Requirements:

- Must work with mobile devices (phones, etc).
- I don't want to use youtube.com or facebook.com as the platform.

I will run my own Linux server, so I don't care what protocol would be used, either HTTP or something else more specific to video.

Comment: @armin - No sorry I haven't moved forward with any research on this. If you do, please let me know. Eventually I'll look into this. I thought this would be relatively easy - something like get Tomcat + some components and viola! Guess not? We'll see. Cheers friend :)